# How to assign value of variable to another method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

my code is as follow

```
 function myFunction(a,b,d)
        {
         var R  = a;
         var G =  b ;
         var B =  d ;
         var L = "(";
         var C = ",";
         var Rp = ")";
         var E = L ;
         var ic = '"';
         var prefix = "RGB";
         var color = ic+prefix + L + R+ C + G + C + B + Rp+ic;
         alert(color)
         var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
         var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
         ctx.fillStyle = color;
        }
```

if i call the above function  for example `myFunction(10,20,30);`  `alert(color);` prints "rgb(10,20,30)" but  i don't know how to assign the value of color to ctx.fillStyle
Since i want to make dynamic application i need pass different value of color , right now  the code doesn't work and `ctx.fillStyle = color;` is printed when code is executed. I will be thankful if some one can tell me how to assign the value of color to ctx.fillStyle method.

Comment: can't see how it'd print `rgb` when you're putting `RGB` in there. Remember that CSS is case-sensitive.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
      </canvas>

     <script type="text/javascript">
       var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
       var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
       ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.arc(70,18,15,0,Math.PI*2,true);
       ctx.closePath();
       ctx.fill();
    </script>

   </body>
</html>
The orignal code is as above all i want to do is make ctx.fillstyle dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You are able to reference a variable for the desired color value as you're wanting to do, so long as the value being provided is a valid color value.

Based off of your provided code, it appears that you are using `RGB` instead of `rgb`.

Comment: in the first line it prints 'rgb(255,0,0)'  which  is ok but when i debug the next line using alert(ctx.fillStyle); it shows black color which is default. even the value of color is printing right but it is not assigning it 'rgb(255,0,0)' . Any insight will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "color" is a string variable here and to use it as a code segment use `eval();` function. Secondly, set some visible area in the canvas to see if the code is really working i.e. ctx.fillRect(). Lastly, make sure your document type is declared as `<!DOCTYPE html>` which I hope is .

Here is the working version of the code (works for me in FF 11.0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script >
function myFunction(a,b,d)
            {
             var R  = a;
             var G =  b;
             var B =  d;
             var L = "(";
             var C = ",";
             var Rp = ")";
             var E = L ;
             var ic = '"';
             var prefix = "RGB";
             var color = ic+prefix + L + R+ C + G + C + B + Rp+ic;

    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle=eval(color); //convert string to code.
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);//any size greater than 0
            }
</script>
<body>
<button  onclick="myFunction(200,0,0);">click me</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the above has to do with variable the string RGB(10,20,30) is never printed , all it does it  take color as string and assign it to  ctx.fillStyle